# Strange highlight of a button in webpage

Tags: html, css, web, button

I tried styling a website and when I press TAB to go through the buttons a strange highlight occurred. it supposed to be just the border of the button, but in the image provided it does not look that way. I would be happy if you could let me know why.
Here are the css and the html iamges of the code/design.

```css
.pagination-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.pagbut {
  background-color: white;
  width: 16px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #06d6a0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-fill {
  background-color: #06d6a0;
}
```

```html
      <div class="pagination-buttons pagi-design">
        <button class="pagbut">&nbsp;</button>
        <button class="pagbut button-fill">&nbsp;</button>
        <button class="pagbut">&nbsp;</button>
        <button class="pagbut">&nbsp;</button>
      </div>
```

[image: IMAGE of strange shape that forms.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the `&nbsp;` this renders a space, which also has a height even tough you can't see it.

So when you select the button, you also select the text inside.

Two solutions for your problem: Remove the space (like I did with the first button) or set the `overflow: hidden` to the button, so that text doesn't overflow the container.

```css
.pagination-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.pagbut {
  background-color: white;
  width: 16px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #06d6a0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-fill {
  background-color: #06d6a0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination-buttons pagi-design">
        <button class="pagbut"></button>
        <button class="pagbut button-fill">&nbsp;</button>
        <button class="pagbut">&nbsp;</button>
        <button class="pagbut">&nbsp;</button>
      </div>
```